# Rails: how to assign a link to image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to make images in page linkable. My code is:

```
<%= image_tag p.photos.first.avatar.url(:small) if p.photos.size > 0 %>
```

How to make this linkable?

Tried doing this:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag p.photos.first.avatar.url(:small) if p.photos.size > 0), product_path(p.id) %>
```

But gives syntax error.

Any one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the link to use the block form (for better readability)

```
<%= link_to product_path(p.id) do %>
  <% if p.photos.any? %>
    <%= image_tag(p.photos.first.avatar.url(:small)) %>
  <% else %>
    <div>Default text for the link if the image is not present</div>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: This is really awesome. Im doing rails for 2 years now but I didnt know that link_to can deal with blocks^^

Comment: wow! worked like charm. Thanks a lot. Was looking for solution from many days. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to image_tag(p.photos.first.avatar.url(:small)).html_safe, product_path(p.id) if p.photos.size > 0%>
```